# Why is the PowerMock.whenNew not working here?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have this simple class:

```
import java.io.File;

public class TestPowerMock {
    public File createFileAndReturnIt() {
        return new File("/");
    }
}
```

And this simple test:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestPowerMock.class)
class TestTestPowerMock {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        TestPowerMock testPowerMock = new TestPowerMock();

        File fileAndReturnIt = testPowerMock.createFileAndReturnIt();
        File mockFile = mock(File.class);

        when(mockFile.getTotalSpace()).thenReturn(1L);
        when(mockFile.getFreeSpace()).thenReturn(2L);

        whenNew(File.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(mockFile);

        System.out.println(fileAndReturnIt.getFreeSpace());
    }
}
```

According to my test mocking scenario, the stout should be printed with 2L right ? Yet I still have the actual "/" folder size.

I did call the PrepareForTest and the RunWith properly no ? Why is it not working ?

My mockito-core version is 3.0.0 but also tested with 5.11 and 2.23.0 and also without it, powermock is 2.0.9 and powermock-apit-mockito2 is 2.0.9 as well.

Also tried with any(), and the method withNoArguments but same result.

Comment: You're calling the method before setting up the mocks - that would be my first guess at the problem. You should mock first, then call the verified method.

Comment: What do you mean I call the method before the mocks. I call getFreeSpace at the very end.

Comment: `testPowerMock.createFileAndReturnIt()` creates the object without PowerMock involvement as you're calling the method before mocking the behaviour. Then you're setting up the mocking that has no effect. After that you're only calling a method on already created object that is not a mock.

Comment: I think you're not aware of what I'm trying to do. This is a constructor mock, it's suppose to mock every call to the constructor in the class. You can see that with with the whenNew and the different anotation PrepareForTest and RunWith.